# How does Scala's Try type work under the hood?

Tags: scala

It seems that `Try` doesn't exhibit behavior I'd expect from a type in how it's able to catch exceptions. I took a look [at the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala), but still don't see how it works.

Is it using some Scala feature I'm unfamiliar with or is this treated specially by the compiler?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I think you just missed out the apply method on line 190: `try Success(r) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing special here. Look at the `apply` method:

```
def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
```

It's literally just wrapping `try`/`catch` by trying to return `Success(r)`, and if that fails, it returns `Failure(e)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's all there:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L192

```
def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
  try Success(r) catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import scala.util._
  import scala.util.control.NonFatal
```

Next 3 lines will use the same `apply` method on `scala.util.Try` object:

```
  val res = Try.apply(throw new Exception)
  val res2 = Try(throw new Exception)
  val res3 = Try { throw new Exception }
```

which has the following definition:

```
  def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
```

1. `apply` method is defined with ByName parameter `r`, which is
   evaluated only when used. In our case it will be used in `try` block
   for `Success(r)`.
2. By convention in Scala you can use parentheses
   to call object's `apply` method.
3. Also by convention you can use
   curly braces to pass a single argument to method.